# How to selected option in ajax data in laravel

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel

How can I selected return success data in page load in laravel AJax.

here is my code. but it doesn't work

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax({
                ....
                success: function (data) {
                    // console.log(x);
                    $('#section').children().remove();
                    var options = "<option>Select one</option>";
                    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
//here is the problem
         options += "<option value= '" + data[i]['slug'] + "' "+ ({{ app('request')->input('section') }} == data[i]['slug'] ? 'selected' : '') +">" + data[i]['section_name'] + "</option>";
// endhere

                    }
                    $('#section').append(options);
                }
            });
        });
```

it is problem inside for loop when making my options. please help

Comment: What is the secret problem?

Comment: You can't use php in the success callback. Php runs on server long before javascript will run this in browser. Php doesn't exist in browser

Comment: Can tou post the select element of your form?

Comment: how can I check my old data with the responsed one? any idea? I want to selected that item inside ajax

Comment: Need a more detailed explanation of what you want to check and what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: {{ app('request')->input('section') }}  this value want to check with ajax data[i]['slug']  if it matched then it will selected

Comment: {{ app('request')->input('section')== data[i]['slug] ? 'selected' : ''}}

like this

Comment: `app('request')` does not exist client side. Only on server. Do this server side and pass it to the json response

Comment: can you plz elaborate? or give me an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do something like that. But no ones do this kind of weird php javascript mix for 20 years. Nowaday, we make SPA apps that call a laravel api.

```
        const last = '{{ app('request')->input('section') }}';
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax({
                ....
                success: function (data) {
                    // console.log(x);
                    $('#section').children().remove();
                    var options = "<option>Select one</option>";
                    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
//here is the problem
         options += "<option value= '" + data[i]['slug'] + "' "+ (last == data[i]['slug'] ? 'selected' : '') +">" + data[i]['section_name'] + "</option>";
// endhere

                    }
                    $('#section').append(options);
                }
            });
        });
```

You should learn about Array methods and template string too.
https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

You can replace the for loop by something like:

```
const options = data.map(d => `<option value="${d.slug}"` ${last === d.slug ? 'selected' : ''}>${d.section_name}</option>`).join('')
```

To get rid of the ".." + "..'" ... hell :P

Comment: I will check the new style. thanks for your suggestion.